# Trying to play sound when image clicked

Tags: java, android

I have an imageview where I'm loading images from drawable.
Now I want to play a sound when an image is clicked.
How do I achieve that? I tried as far as I could but failing everytime. Please suggest a way out.
Currently, I am able to display a Toast when an image is clicked.

**This is my ViewPagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.apple,R.drawable.litchi,R.drawable.passionfruit,R.drawable.mango};
    MediaPlayer apple_mp,litchi_mp,passionfruit_mp,mango_mp;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) { this.context = context; }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return images.length; }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) { return view == object; }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruitsView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        apple_mp = MediaPlayer.create(Fruits, R.raw.apple);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position == 0){ Toast.makeText(context, "Apple clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                else if (position == 1){ Toast.makeText(context, "Litchi clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                else if (position == 2){ Toast.makeText(context, "Passion fruit clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                else { Toast.makeText(context, "Mango  clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
            }
        });

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

**This is my Fruits.java**

```
package com.example.splashscreen;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Fruits extends Dashboard {
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruits);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerFruit);
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
 if (position == 0){ Toast.makeText(context, "Apple clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
apple_mp.start()
}

Comment: @Suman Chhetri  refer this  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions but I have gone through that already. My problematic code is **ViewPagerAdapter.java** on line 36.`apple_mp = MediaPlayer.create(Fruits, R.raw.apple);`. The Fruits class is not identified and when I hover my mouse over it, there's a message **Expression expected: Create field 'fruits' in 'ViewPagerAdapter'**.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm getting error on the first line of your code at `this` and the hover message shows **Cannot resolve method 'create(com.example.splashscreen.ViewPagerAdapter,int)'**. So, `mp.start()'` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

apple_mp.start()

```
 public void onClick(View v) { 
        if (position == 0){ 
            Toast.makeText(context, "Apple clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            apple_mp.start()
         }
```

Comment: `apple_mp.start()` will not work here because the declaration `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);` does not recognize `this` and it gives me following text when I hover over `this`: **Cannot resolve method 'create(com.example.splashscreen.ViewPagerAdapter,int)'**.

Comment: The correct way to implement feature is to pass callback from an adapter to activity.
and init your media player in the activity and based on the position click set raw type. and start a media player. 


This will help you in releasing media player based on the activity lifecycle and you will not get this cannot resolved error

Answer (score 0):

Create new Folder inside Res folder with name "raw"
Inside "raw" folder put any mp3 file.

create new class Accompaniment.kt

```
class Accompaniment private constructor(context: Context?, private val myResSoundId: Int) {
    private var mBarcodeMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var ownersContext: Context? = null
    private var isReleased = false
    private var mAudioManager: AudioManager? = null

    init {
        if (context == null) throw IllegalArgumentException("context cannot be null")
        ownersContext = context
    }

    enum class RingerMode {
        SILENT, VIBRATE, NORMAL
    }

    private fun ringerMode(): RingerMode {
        if (mAudioManager == null) {
            mAudioManager = ownersContext!!.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        }
        return RingerMode.values()[mAudioManager!!.ringerMode]
    }

    fun start(): Boolean {
        return start(false)
    }

    /* fun startForce(): Boolean {
         return start(true)
     }*/

    @Synchronized
    private fun start(forceInSilence: Boolean): Boolean {
        if (isReleased) {
            return false
        }
        if (mBarcodeMediaPlayer == null) {
            mBarcodeMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ownersContext, myResSoundId)
            if (mBarcodeMediaPlayer == null) {
                return false
            }
        }

        if (!(forceInSilence || ringerMode() == RingerMode.NORMAL)) {
            return false
        }

        mBarcodeMediaPlayer!!.start()

        return true
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun release() {
        isReleased = true
        if (mBarcodeMediaPlayer != null) {
            mBarcodeMediaPlayer!!.release()
            mBarcodeMediaPlayer = null
        }
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstanceOfResource(contxt: Context, resId: Int): Accompaniment {
            return Accompaniment(contxt, resId)
        }
    }
}
```

Now come on your activity or Adapter class and create instance of the above class like this.

```
 private val mAccompaniment = Accompaniment.newInstanceOfResource(this, R.raw.tag_inventoried)
```

on button click or any event start the ring or stop the ring in below way-

```
 mAccompaniment.start()

 mAccompaniment.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to start the MediaPlayer:

`apple_mp.start();`

Also, add this in your onBackPressed method :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if(apple_mp!=null) {
            apple_mp.release();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but `apple_mp.start()` will not work here because the declaration `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);` does not recognize `this` and it gives me following text when I hover over `this`: **Cannot resolve method 'create(com.example.splashscreen.ViewPagerAdapter,int)'**.

Comment: Yes, "this" won't work because it is an Adapter and not an Activity. So, you can pass the Context as an argument to your Adapter's constructor and use that here: MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.soho);

Comment: Could you show me how? I couldn't figure a way out :-(

Comment: I noticed that you have already done what I said, now instead of "this" just pass "context" as the argument to the create method in the ViewPagerAdapter class.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. I put exactly `context` instead of `this` and it worked. However, I have a activity_fruits.xml as parent and have another custom_layout.xml as it's child. Both of them doesn't contain anything important, except ImageView tags. The problem is, the sound plays when clicked on parent and child screen. How do I play the sound in child screen (custom_layout.xml) only?

Comment: Your description about custom_layout.xml is not clear. If you could share those xml files and give a more clear description, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Never mind Vaidhya, I resolved the .xml part on my own :-) Thanks anyways.